# Is it possible to do Server -> Facebook authentication?

Tags: java, facebook

My quick investigations appear to suggest that FB has deprecated all auth mechanisms while leaving their custom oauth implementation.

Can someone comment or clarify this statement ?

Why ?

- I want users to authenticate against my app and not FB
- At some later stage i wish to grab some assets from FB such as the current users photo etc.

Comment: I think you **authenticate** against FB, and the user **authorizes** your app to use his person information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need at least once to let them authenticate with the facebook ID and authorize your app. From that moment, you will receive an `access_token` in the JSON response that will allow you to perform operations for your user.

There are two types of access tokens:

- **Session based**: expires in a short term, are used when the user will be logged to FB every time you need to perform an operation.
- **Offline access**: do not expire and allow the app to perform operations for the user in any moment. This requires the `offline_access` permission when the app is authorized.

Check here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ for the oauth mechanism and here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/ for the permissions list.

Comment: Thanks i thought i heard somewhere that this sort of permanent even if it is time limit authentication was removed.

Comment: It will be permanent for as long as the user doesn't deauthorize the app. One caveat, though: there have been some reports in the fb devs forum about offline tokens that expired, although it's not clear why. I would have a fallback mechanism just in case (i.e., check for an error about token expired or similar, and if you get one, have the user log into fb an reauthorize.