# Facebook API Authentication in Coldfusion without login box

Tags: authentication, coldfusion, facebook-graph-api, authorization

I have been looking for information on how to authenticate to the facebook api without a login button and haven't been able to find anything. Essentially I want to pull data from a static user (I don't want to pull information about every person that visits the page specifically, I want to pull information from a specific user account).

I want to convert the feed I retrieve into an rss feed, or an ATOM feed for my client to display in their website.

Is there any information about how to authenticate in this way?

An example of info I would want to pull would be to pull the wall posts from their facebook account and display them as a feed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter what you do, login button or not, you will have to have your user Authenticate with your application in order to retrieve any sort of data.

The easiest way to do it is to use either the facebook login button or use the Javascript SDK and do something like this...

```
    FB.login(function(response) {
  if (response.session) {
    if (response.perms) {
      // user is logged in and granted some permissions.
      // perms is a comma separated list of granted permissions
    } else {
      // user is logged in, but did not grant any permissions
    }
  } else {
    // user is not logged in
  }
}, {perms:'read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access'});
```

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/
Then once you get the user authenticated you can grab the cookie that is created by doing

```
<cfscript>
var fbcookie = cookie.fbs_YOURAPIKEYGOESHERE;
</cfscript>
```

There is more info on the cookie here...
http://jcreamerlive.com/2011/01/12/facebook-and-coldfusion/

From there you can use the javascript FB.api and do FQL queries http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Or you can use cfhttp posts to the Graph API
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Have fun!

Comment: So there is no way to handle authentication from the back end? Like I can supply a username and password from the serverside code for authentication.

Comment: Here is where facebook talks about server side connectivity http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ Basically you post to the authorization URL, and give it a callback URL. Then facebook posts some stuff to your callback url and you grab that out of their post.

Comment: So what I think you are trying to say is to just manually go through the steps of the authentication/authorization to start with. And with the offline_access permission just get the key and store it for later use?  Or will the key still expire?

Answer (score 0):

You need to authenticate the app using oauth2 method with a offline_access permission. You will get an access token that does not require user login to access to the account. 
I give a more detail and links to the relevant fb documentation pages in this answer:

[Is it possible to do Server -> Facebook authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616645/is-it-possible-to-do-server-facebook-authentication/5616692#5616692)

Comment: are there any instructions. The facebook documentation shows how to set things up using an oauth dialog.